# After installing Dart commands like pub, dart2js are not found

Tags: apt, package-management, googledart

I've installed Dart according to instructions from the official website (https://www.dartlang.org/tools/debian.html). To be more exactly:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https
# Get the Google Linux package signing key.
$ sudo sh -c 'curl https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -'
# Set up the location of the stable repository.
$ sudo sh -c 'curl https://storage.googleapis.com/download.dartlang.org/linux/debian/dart_stable.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dart_stable.list'
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install dart
```

Installation was successful, but some time later I found that there is no other related commands like pub, dart2js.

```
pub: command not found
dart2js: command not found
```

What's wrong?

OS: Ubuntu 14.10

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I know nothing about Dart, yet I downloaded the deb and looked inside it. The files you're looking for are located at `/usr/lib/dart/bin/`. You're getting "command not found" because that directory is not in `$PATH`.

You should be able to run them by providing the full path:

```
/usr/lib/dart/bin/dart2js
```

Or you may want to [add `/usr/lib/dart/bin` to $PATH](https://askubuntu.com/q/60218/65926).

Comment: Thanks, I've already installed Dart manually using ~/.profile :)

Comment: I decided, "pub" was a little vague or too general.  So i made a link instead, `ln -s /usr/lib/dart/bin/pub ~/bin/util/dart-pub`  -- I could have called it "pub", the main point from my side is that `~/bin/util` is _already_ in my PATH.

Answer (score 4):

Another way to fix it using symlinks

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/dart/bin/pub /usr/bin/pub
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/dart/bin/dart2js /usr/bin/dart2js
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a bit late , but I am putting this for future reference 
As @Eric mentioned , dart directory needs to be added to your PATH .

These steps can be followed to add /usr/lib/dart/bin to your PATH on ubuntu:

```
$ sudo nano .profile
```

Then add this line to your .profile file :

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/dart/bin
```

Then you need to reload your .profile file :

```
. ~/.profile
```